# Custom JavaScript log function

Tags: javascript

I am having some issues in my production code and I want to be able to send a flag to enable/disable JS logging, so I want to write my own logging function.

I want to use something like `function log(){...}`. When I looked up [reserved words in JS](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDcQFjAA&url=https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words&ei=NkvrUPnJJ4iU2wXmqYG4CA&usg=AFQjCNHsPuXuhYKEPqjMeG_ItOsvVTY4bA&sig2=bWNcRABSMxEvLdZabE54vw&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.b2I) I didn't see
log listed, but I do see it listed in the w3schools docs as a [math function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_log.asp).

Is it okay to use log() as a function name in production code for IE 7+, Chrome, and FF?

Comment: w3schools is not affiliated with w3c in any way at all, they are an authority on nothing.

Comment: @WesleyMurch But that doesn't mean anything in the context of the question, their info about `Math.log` existing is completely valid

Comment: @JuanMendes: "The w3 docs" as the author states, is misleading. I'm trying to help.

Comment: @WesleyMurch You're correct, sorry, I didn't notice the OP referred to w3schools documentation as `w3 docs` I share the same hate for w3 schools that many competent web devs have.

Comment: @WesleyMurch How does that help in answering the question?

Comment: For clarity, I updated 'w3 docs' to 'w3schools docs'.

Comment: @Justin http://w3fools.com/ Don't use W3Schools, their info on this was fine, but there are plenty of outdated practices, and even wrong information there

Comment: @SajjanSarkar: It's not an answer, it's a *comment*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely fine. The maths `log` function is a function on the `Math` object, so will not collide with your implementation.

If you are confused by this sort of thing, look into JavaScript 'namespaces'

[How do I declare a namespace in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/javascript-namespace-declaration)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is ok. The math `log` function is available as `Math.log`, not `log` so you won't break anything...

Answer (score 0):

That should be fine. The mathematical `log` function is called via `Math.log(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is ok. The math log function always needs to be called as `Math.log()`. So you're fine.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using an existing object or namespace rather than making your log function global.

See http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/06/01/global-domination/